# How to fill a Symfony choice widget dynamically with the result of a DB query

Tags: drop-down-menu, symfony1, symfony-1.4

In one of my forms I would like to have a dropdown (sfWidgetFormChoice) where the options are generated dynamically by executing a query on the database.

To be a little bit more precise, I'm going to list all versions which I have in the table. The query looks something like this:

```
select distinct version from mytable order by version desc
```

What I have so far but doesn't work:

```
class myForm extends sfForm

$query = "select distinct version from mytable order by version desc";

$versions = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->fetchAssoc($query);

public function configure()

$this->setWidgets(array('version' => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => self::$versions))));
```

**Edit:**

Thansk guys for your answers! Much appreciated!

Anyhow your solutions base on having a model of the table. I'd rather have a PDO directly as it's faster.

In the [Symfony Documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/08-Inside-the-Model-Layer-Doctrine) I found what I was looking for under "Using Raw SQL Queries".

So I extended my Form to end up with this:

```
class myForm extends sfForm
{
  public function getVersions()
  {
    $connection = Doctrine_Manager::connection();
    $query      = "select distinct version from mytable order by version desc";
    $statement  = $connection->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $resultset = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

    return $resultset;
  }

  public function configure()
  {
    $this->setWidgets(array('version' => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => self::getVersions()))));
  }
}
```

As a result of this my dropdown gets properly filled with what is in my table, yay! BUT I get also warnings:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/database/sfDoctrineConnectionProfiler.class.php on line 196
>
> Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/database/sfDoctrineConnectionProfiler.class.php on line 141
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/database/sfDoctrineConnectionProfiler.class.php on line 196
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/debug/sfDoctrineConnectionProfiler.class.php on line 117

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here??? Oddly enough the dropdown looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution I was looking for by myself. This accesses the DB now directly. The reason why I don't use FETCH_COLUMN anymore is that this would create an array where the key is an Id starting from 0 and the value is whatever is returned by the query itself. Instead I wanted to have the key and value to be whatever the query delivers. This is why the query now delivers two columns being the same and then FETCH_KEY_PAIR does the rest.

In case anyone else is interested in how I solved this, here is my code which is filling the drop down properly and causing no errors.

```
class myForm extends sfForm
{
  public function getVersions()
  {
    $connection = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->getDBh();
    $query      = "select distinct version as key, version as value from mytable order by version desc";
    $statement  = $connection->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $resultset = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);

    return $resultset;
  }

  public function configure()
  {
    $this->setWidgets(array('version' => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => self::getVersions()))));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a really really bad use of the forms and widget and it's not MVC at all. `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice` with custom query is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `table_method` option of [`sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice) like this :

In your form class do this :

```
$this->setWidgets(array('version' => new sfWidgetDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'Version', 'table_method' => 'getData')));
```

then in the `versionTable.class.php` file create a `getData()` (you can call this anything) function that returns a collection of objects :

```
public function getData() {
    $this->getInstance()->createQuery()
          ->orderBy('version desc')
          ->execute();
}
```

Comment: You need to remove "()" from .. 'table_method' => 'getData()'. It has to be `'table_method' => 'getData'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice**

```
public function configure(){

$this->widgetSchema['version'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'YourModel', 'query' => Doctrine::getTable('YurModel')->getYourDataQuery(), 'add_empty' => true));

}
```

And in your **modelTable.class.php**

```
 public function getYourDataQuery()
    {
          //Your query

            $q = $this->createQuery('a');         

        return $q;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you sir, I really appreciate your solution.
you have saved my day!

Just in case anyone who's having similar issues.
I ran into a PDO not found problem when using the solution.
(FatalErrorException: Error: Class '.......\Controller\PDO' not found in )
Reason being:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/mR22XXKPQrk
"You are misusing the PHP namespaces. When you are in a namespaced code, 
using PDO means a class name relative to the current namespace. You have 
2 solutions to fix your issue: using a fully qualified class name like 
\PDO or adding a use statement to import the class in the current namespace."

So After adding the '\' in front of PDO::, the solution works perfectly.

Thanks!